# Initializing java.awt.geom.Point2D

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am developing using Java SE on NetBeans 7.3.1 on Windows 7.  I write the following code.

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

static void setDisplayParams(Vector<Point2D> coords, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax){
    Point2D newCoords, oldCoords;
    Vector<Point2D> displayCoords = new Vector<Point2D>();

    for (int i=0; i<coords.size(); ++i){
                oldCoords=coords.elementAt(i);
                newCoords.setLocation(oldCoords.getX(), yMax-oldCoords.getY());
                displayCoords.add(newCoords);
    }
}
```

At the line

```
newCoords.setLocation(oldCoords.getX(), yMax-oldCoords.getY());
```

I get the message

```
variable newCoords might not have been initialzed
```

I Googled

```
java.awt.geom.Point2D initializing java
```

and read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) that

```
Point2D.Double()
```

is supposed to initialize a java.awt.geom.Point2D variable.  However newCoords does not have a field Double.

My for loop was initially

```
                for (int i=0; i<coords.size(); ++i){
                newCoords=coords.elementAt(i);
                newCoords.setLocation(newCoords.getX(), yMax-newCoords.getY());
                displayParams.displayCoords.add(newCoords);
            }
```

This did not give me any error messages but it changed the values in coords which I do not want to do.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a static reference like this.

```
for (int i=0; i<coords.size(); ++i){
    newCoords=coords.elementAt(i);
    displayParams.displayCoords.add(new Point2D.Double(newCoords.getX(), yMax-newCoords.getY()));
}
```

This will create a new Point2D and leave our newCoords (element in the array) object unchanged.